# How to upgrade Artemis on WildFly

Tags: java, wildfly, activemq-artemis

We are using WildFly 10.1.0.Final which ships with Artemis 1.1.0.wildfly-017, and we want to upgrade it to the latest maintenance version [1.1.0.SP18-redhat-1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/artemis-jms-server) (also considering 1.4.0 as well).

How can I upgrade Artemis without having to manually build WildFly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also interested to know, as artemis-hawtio plugin is no more compatible with Artemis 1.1:

https://github.com/rh-messaging/artemis-hawtio/issues/17

I still haven't tried, but one solution could be to to replace/upgrade all the Artemis libs in:

${WILDFLY_HOME}/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/activemq/artemis/main/lib

Do not forget to update "module.xml" accordingly.

Comment: I would like to add that upgrading an embedded component, such as Artemis for WildFly, means that integration incompatibilities may happen. While "support package" versions will mostly focus on "minor" adjustments like performance enhancements, bug corrections and security patches, the risk of integration problems still exists between other WildFly modules. Such an operation is risky and it means that you should read about the changes applied and test it.